# Is the annotationType of an AnnotationMirror associated with the wrong module by javac?

Tags: javac, annotation-processing

Suppose I have the following in some unit test code somewhere, patched into a module named `com.foo.main` (name doesn't matter, only that this test code is running as part of a module):

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test // name probably doesn't matter
final void testSomething() { /* ... */ }
```

(The module patching is due to the ordinary behavior of Maven's `maven-surefire-plugin` which can make code running under `test-classes` appear to the JPMS as if it were part of the Java module defined by `classes/module-info.class`.  It works fine and I don't think it is the source of the issue here. The important fact is that for all intents and purposes the unit test code belongs, at runtime, to the `com.foo.main` module, and clearly `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` does not.)

I am noticing in my (unfortunately somewhat convoluted) annotation processing scenario that the `AnnotationMirror` corresponding to `@Test` above contains an `annotationType` whose `TypeKind` is `ERROR`, not `DECLARED` (as I would have expected).  I'm not doing anything fancy; just getting the `AnnotationMirror` via the `ExecutableElement` representing this method, and looking at its `annotationType`.

From debugging the compiler (!) I notice that `Symtab`, while building all of the scaffolding for handing me back an `AnnotationMirror`, [wants to enter `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` into the symbol table under the `com.foo.main` module](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-20%2B36/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symtab.java#L784), not under its own module or any other module, including an unnamed module.  This appears to be the case because the module that is "in effect" during the reading of the `testSomething` method is that of its declaring class (so `com.foo.main`).

This only occurs when this `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` type is completed as part of an annotation.  That is, when I ask for it directly (via, say, `Elements#getTypeElement("org.junit.jupiter.api.Test")`) its `TypeKind` is `DECLARED` as expected.

I think the ultimate culprit is in [`ClassReader.java#classSigToType()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-20%2B36/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/ClassReader.java#L535-L550), which is used to read the type information from the runtime visible annotations attribute (i.e. the part that reads "`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`"), but then reuses the `enterClass` method, which applies the "current module", which in this case is, incorrectly?, `com.foo.main`.

The `ERROR` kind seems to come about because the `classfile` member of the `ClassSymbol` corresponding to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` is `null` during annotation type symbol completion, perhaps? because of the strange module association.  This is where my brain's overload protection circuit kicked in so I am not confident in this assessment.

Is this a known gotcha to watch out for, or is this a reasonable candidate for a compiler bug?

Comment: It has been a few weeks since you posted with no follow-up - did you end up deciding to try to report this as a bug? Going by your description (without having any code to run and try out), it certainly looks that way to me, but I would encourage providing at least a simple example with your bug report.